# can I mix the header titles in listview

Tags: winapi

I know by using `listview_getheader` you can get the header info from the list view, but what about set the header is there any macro for that?

what I want to do is this

```
|     Title     |
|item 1 |subitem|
|item 2 |subitem|
|item 3 |subitem|
|item 4 |subitem|
|item 5 |subitem|
|item 6 |subitem|
```

Comment: Not sure why the downvote.  The question seems reasonable to me.

Answer (score 1):

ListView_GetHeader() gets the handle for the header.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761290(v=vs.85).aspx

> Gets the handle to the header control used by a list-view control. You can use this macro or send the LVM_GETHEADER message explicitly.

With the handle, you should be able to get or set the associated text with SetWindowText().

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633546(v=vs.85).aspx

> Changes the text of the specified window's title bar (if it has one). If the specified window is a control, the text of the control is changed.